# Sequelize - Counting associations and fetching data from association with query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm creating a Twitter-like application using sequelize(Postgres as a database). There are 3 tables - users, posts, and postlikes. Now while listing posts I want to fetch a total number of likes and the current user has liked that post or not. So how can I achieve this with sequelize?

I've created a simple query but don't know what to do next. postlikes table has postId and userId. I'm including the user in the below query to get data of the author of the post.

```
let allPosts = await db.Post.findAndCountAll({
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
      offset: offset * limit,
      limit: limit,
      include: [
        {
          model: db.User,
          as: 'user',
          attributes: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'username', 'profilePic'],
          raw: true,
        },
        {
          model: db.PostLike,
          as: 'postlikes',
          raw: true,
        },
      ],
    });
```

I found the below code on stackoverflow and tried but couldn't get any result:

```
attributes: [
        [
          db.Sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.Sequelize.col('postlikes.id')),
          'likeCount',
        ],
      ],
```

Got this error- original: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "postlikes"

So please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model: `Post.js`

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Post extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            this.hasMany(models.PostLike, {
                foreignKey: "postId",
                as: "postlikes",
            });
        }
    }
    Post.init({
        type: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "Post",
    });
    return Post;
};
```

Model: `PostLike.js`

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class PostLike extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            this.belongsTo(models.Post, {
                foreignKey: "postId",
                as: "post",
            });
        }
    }

    PostLike.init({
        postId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "PostLike",
    });
    return PostLike;
};
```

Controller

```
var post = await db.Post.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id',
        [db.Sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.Sequelize.col('postlikes.id')), 'likeCount',],
    ],
    include: ['postlikes']
})
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(post)))
process.exit()
```

**Output:**

```
[ { id: 1, likeCount: 56, postlikes: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/blob/stack-66515305/test/db.js Check this project, and its test code, **stack-66515305** branch